# How to force Windows Device Manager refresh device name display after I change FriendlyName registry value

Tags: windows, device-driver

Microsoft WDK's Toaster sample code contains a ClassInstaller example(tostrcls.dll). It shows the ability to customize "device friendly name" displayed by Device Manager. The ability is achieved by modifying FriendlyName's value for the device's *hardware key* . After modifying FriendlyName, a close and reopen of the Device Manager window(devmgmt.msc) will reflect such changes. So far, so good.

However, in order to tell Device Manager window to reflect the change immediately(without close and reopen its window), some extra code has to be run. `classInst.c` takes the following way:

```
spDevInstall.FlagsEx |= DI_FLAGSEX_PROPCHANGE_PENDING;

SetupDiSetDeviceInstallParams(Params->DeviceInfoSet,
                              Params->DeviceInfoData,
                              &spDevInstall);
```

That works, but **NOT** optimal. `DI_FLAGSEX_PROPCHANGE_PENDING` causes the device to go through a STOP/START cycle. I mean, the driver's ToasterEvtDeviceReleaseHardware and ToasterEvtDevicePrepareHardware get executed. I think this is an undesired side-effect.

So my question is clear. Is there a way to refresh Device Manager's display without bothering with the driver code?

[image: Toaster FriendlyName]

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from WDK7 PnpPorts project(which is the ClassInstaller that implement the Windows COM Port "Port Setting" tab).

Just change

```
spDevInstall.FlagsEx |= DI_FLAGSEX_PROPCHANGE_PENDING;
```

to

```
spDevInstall.Flags |= DI_PROPERTIES_CHANGE;
```

all done.

Note: The device-restarting behavior of `DI_FLAGSEX_PROPCHANGE_PENDING` is documented in WDK7 chm page "DIF_ADDPROPERTYPAGE_ADVANCED" but not in "SP_DEVINSTALL_PARAMS". I only check the latter, so missed it.